# Redirecting stdout and stderr and elevate to administrator using START-PROCESS

Tags: powershell

As part of our server build and configuration which is all done using Powershell, I need to remotely install .net framework 4.5.1 on a number of Server 2012 machines. [The offline install](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40779) ships as an .exe which, when run, unpacks a number of MSI installers and a setup program.

The code we use to run installers can work with MSI files or exe's. If we use MSI files then a call is made to MSIEXEC and if it is an EXE then that program is called directly. Any arguments required can also be passed.

For our purposes this is acheived using the Powershell cmdlet Start-Process.

I need to get the return code to work out whether the install has completed correctly and would also like to capture stdout and stderr to help diagnose any problems if the installation failed.

I have the following custom written function to wrap the Start-Process cmdlet.

```
Function Start-Proc()
{
[CmdletBinding()]
    param (
    [string][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][ValidateScript({Test-Path -Path $_ -Type Leaf})] $FilePath,
    [string][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$Arguments,
    [switch] $Hidden,
    [switch] $WaitForExit
    )

#Create files to hold the output to avoid the deadlock issue that seems to arise when we read
#the output and error at the same time http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx
$errorFilePath = Join-Path -Path $env:TEMP -ChildPath ([system.guid]::NewGuid().ToString())
$outputFilePath = Join-Path -Path $env:TEMP -ChildPath ([system.guid]::NewGuid().ToString())

$process = Start-Process `
                -FilePath $FilePath `
                -ArgumentList $Arguments `
                -RedirectStandardError $errorFilePath `
                -RedirectStandardOutput $outputFilePath `
                -NoNewWindow:$Hidden `
                -PassThru `
                -Wait:$WaitForExit

$errorOut = Get-Content -Path $errorFilePath
$stdOut = Get-Content -Path $outputFilePath

#Tidy up files
If ($process.HasExited)
{
    Remove-Item $errorFilePath
    Remove-Item $outputFilePath
}

#Create new object to send the messages and exit code back
$output = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$output | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty -Name Message -Value $stdOut
$output | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty -Name ErrorMessage -Value $errorOut
$output | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty -Name ExitCode -Value $process.ExitCode

return $output
}
```

Note: I have to use the -RedirectStandardOutput and -RedirectStandardInput Params sending the output to files and then using Get-Content to avoid a deadlock reading the properties as text.

Calling this function to install .NET framework 4.5.1 always fails with an error code of 5 which is Access Denied.

Looking into this it appears you need to use the 
    -Verb RunAs
parameter with Start-Process to elevate the command as administrator however adding that parameter to the cmdlet causes the following error:

```
Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
```

This is because -Verb and -RedirectStandardOutput & -RedirectStandardError are in different parameter sets.

My question is therefore:

How can I run an executable from Powershell that does the following:

1. captures the exit code
2. captures the output and error messages
3. runs as elevated administrator

I have already tried using the .NET System.Diagnostics.Process.Start method directly however this suffers from the same problem.

Thanks for any help as this is proving to be a difficult problem!

Answer (score 1):

I would use another script that has parameters such as the exe path, arguments and name of output file and have it return the exit code. Use Start-Process to redirect, wait on the process and get the exit code to return to the parent script. In the parent script use Start-Process -verb runas to launch PowerShell with the script path as an argument as well as the script arguments to launch the script elevated.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, would you mind elaborating a little on this suggestion Keith? I have seen examples of Start-Process calling another version of Powershell however I am not clear which parameters you would use with "parent" script and which you would use with the child in order to get the correct combination of elevation and output redirection.

Comment: In the parent script use -verb runas to start another PowerShell process elevated, use the parameter -ArgumentList "-File c:\child.ps1" to pass the pass to the child script to PowerShell.exe. In the child script start the process you want to run with the redirection parameters and have it return the process's ExitCode.  In both scripts you will use the -PassThru and -Wait parameters to wait for the started process to finish and to get the exit code.

Comment: I have tried what you have suggested and this appears to do what it should however i am still getting "error 0x05 access denied" when installing .net framework 4.5.1 using this process. I am starting to think this is nothing to do with start-process because if I run the same code locally it works. There must be something about it being a remote session (using invoke-command) or because the source file is on a UNC share. Any thoughts on why I am getting access denied appreciated. My next step is to use SysInterals Process Monitor to see what the access denied is for. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you may be running into a second hop issue with credentials.  Use the Invoke-Command parameter `-Authentication CredSSP`.

Comment: Thank you for your continued interest Keith. I have now tried every variation of start-process there is possible I believe. CREDSSP was already being used as the task to install .net 4.5.1 was just one of many in our automation pipeline and we open the session using CREDSSP already whic works great. I still however cannot get .net 4.5.1.installed. I always receive an exit code of 0x05, ACCESS DENIED. Other programs that require admin appear to work. if anyone else has any experience of installing this remotely I would love to hear how they did it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not capturing the exit code - but I do get stdout + stderr. And you could adjust your "script block" to do what you need with this...

```
$output = "c:\temp\psoutput.txt"
$computername = "xxxxxx"
$code = "Stop-WebAppPool -Name `"my.app.pool" 2>&1 >>$output"

$prog = "powershell.exe"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computername -ScriptBlock { param($p,$a,$o) 
                                                            Start-Process $p -ArgumentList $a -wait -verb RunAs
                                                            get-content $o
                                                        } -ArgumentList $prog,$code,$output
```